# Express-session cookies not setting on localhost or Safari?

Tags: node.js, express

It looks like express-session is not setting cookies when working locally or on Safari but they are working fine on Chrome when deployed on Heroku. Never come across this issue before. Below is how I have set up my `app.session()`:

```
app.use(session({
    genid: function(req) {
      return genuuid();
    },
    secret: consts.SECRET_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
}));
```

When the user logs in I set `req.session.user = aValue` and then a resolve on my router checks to see if the server is getting a 200 or 401 back.

Comment: Hi Jack, how do you solve this issue ? Regards

Comment: I had to set my cookie options to httpOnly and make them secure, I also created a mongoStore to store the session cookies in

name: consts.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
      secret: consts.SECRET_KEY,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      resave: true,
      cookie:{
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true
      },
      store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
      })

Comment: Thank you, i will give them a try. I'm setting up with redis but it doesn't work only with safari. chrome & ff works fine.

Comment: No worries, good luck!